# How do you fork and develop a globally installed Node.js NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a fix for a an NPM package that I rather enjoy, [Wintersmith](https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith). However, Wintersmith is supposed to be globally installed (executable with `wintersmith <command>`) and I can't seem to run it from the root of a project where I have it installed locally manually with `git clone <my fork url>` with something like `node ./node_modules/wintersmith/bin/wintersmith` without receiving path errors:

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli/'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (F:\web\wintersmith\node_modules\bin\wintersmith:3:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

The only way I can figure to properly develop and test this is by manually replacing my globally installed Wintersmith package with my forked version and then executing commands using that version to test whether or not my changes are working.

Is there some workflow step that I'm missing when working with/developing global NPM packages?

Answer (score 1):

**You should use `npm install git://` instead `git clone`**

*Install your fork like this:*

```
npm install git://github.com/YOURNAME/wintersmith.git
```

*You can also install it as global module use `-g`:*

```
npm install -g git://github.com/YOURNAME/wintersmith.git
```

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS eats an environment variable `NODE_PATH`. You can make use of that besides `PATH`.

This document describes it better:
http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Answer (score 0):

I can execute wintersmith like this, without having to install it globally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith.git
$ cd wintersmith
$ npm install               # This installs all dependencies I need for the next step.
$ npm run-script prepublish # Run the prepublish script which compiles sources to ./lib
$ bin/wintersmith
```

I get the usage message that it gives when there is nothing passed as arguments.

When creating a node package that is meant to be installed globally it is possible and *desirable* to design it so that it can be run and tested without having to install it. I was surprised that wintersmith would not be designed this way.

Generally speaking, if I had to deal with a node package that cannot be tested without being installed globally, I'd call it "defective". (Maybe there are exceptions but such exceptions are rare and they should be justified in the package's documentation.)

So, generally, if I had to deal with a package that cannot be run and tested without being installed globally, I'd look for a package providing equivalent functionality which *can* be run without being installed globally, or fix the faulty package.